# Filtering Columns from JSON File

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, react-redux, material-ui

I have a project where i have a Json file which looks something like below
I am currently using Older Material UI 4 version with React and I need to filter columns and for each columns it should filter the same file

For example
Name      Roll No      Result
each of these act like filters and should filter out from same json file and the result should be a drop down

Code is like this

```
const rows = [
  {
    name: 'Abhi',
    roll: 1,
    result: 'Pass',
  },{
    name: 'Risho',
    roll: 2,
    result: 'NA',
  },{
    name: 'Foaru',
    roll: 3,
    result: 'A'Bsent,
  },
];

const ResultTable = props => {
  const {
    HeaderDataTable: { headers }
  } = HOME_TEXT;
  const [copyList, setCopyList] = useState(rows);
  const requestSearch = searched => {
    setCopyList(rows.filter(item => item.name.includes(searched)));
  };
  const columnHeaders = Object.values(headers);
  return (
    <TableContainer className='franchise-container-dashboard'>
      <Table
        stickyHeader
      >
        <TableHead  >
          <TableRow >
            {columnHeaders.map(header => (
              <TableCell
                key={header}
                style={{ backgroundColor: '#022a48' }}
              >
                {header} // I have constant defined for that  which is : name ,Roll no ,result 
              </TableCell>
            ))}
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody        >
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>
              <TextField
                variant='outlined'
                placeholder='Search Name'
                type='search'
                onInput={e => requestSearch(e.target.value)}
                style={{ width: '100%' }}
              />
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell>
              <Typography variant='body2'>
                <TextField
                  variant='outlined'
                  placeholder='Search Roll'
                  type='search'
                  onInput={e => requestSearch(e.target.value)}
                  style={{ width: '100%' }}
                />{' '}
              </Typography>
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell>
              <Typography variant='body2'>
                <TextField
                  variant='outlined'
                  placeholder='Search Result'
                  type='search'
                  onInput={e => requestSearch(e.target.value)}
                  style={{ width: '100%' }}
                />
              </Typography>
            </TableCell>            
          </TableRow>
        </TableBody>
        {(copyList.length > 0 ? copyList : originalList).map(
        (class, index) => ( <TableRow     key={index} >
            <TableCell >
              <Typography variant='body2'>{class.Name}</Typography>
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell>
              <Typography variant='body2'>
                {class.roll}
              </Typography>
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell >
              <Typography variant='body2'>{class.result}</Typography>
            </TableCell>
          </TableRow>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
};

export default ResultTable;
```

Can any one please help me or clarify me what i am doing wrong ?

i want to get a filter for all column  on the samejson file that is
if i fill all the filters as well it should filter those file  also possible can result be converted drop down

Answer (score 0):

```
const searchColumns = Object.keys(rows[0]);
const requestSearch = searched => {
  const filterRows = rows.filter(each => {
      var containRow = false;
      for (var i = 0; i < searchColumns.length; i++) {
        if (each[searchColumns[i]] && each[searchColumns[i]].toString().indexOf(searched ) !== -1) {
          containRow = true;
        }
      }
      if (containRow) {
        return each;
      }
    })
    return filterRows ;
}
```

1. below is the example for searching for row 1.

requestSearch('Abhi');

Comment: what happens if I use the above logic and I have  3 column each with a search filter on it, 
will it work  on same json? also One of the filter is drop down as well so will it work

Comment: It will work with one search box using for search for all columns. If you want to add separate filter for each column as header filter that this would not work. you would have to make handler search for each column header filtering from the filtered record if any column has search text before.

Comment: That the challenge  "If you want to add separate filter for each column as header filter that this would not work" I want this actually , its like a filter table where I have 3 columns and each coulmn has a filter so any work around ? @jahanzeb

Comment: You will have to store the searches of every field header in json state.

Answer (score 0):

```
    const [copyList, setCopyList] = useState(rows);
    const [searchColumnsList, setSearchColumnsList] = useState(columnHeaders.map(x=> {return {name:x,searchText:null}}));
    const requestSearch = (searched,fieldName) => {
        let searchColumnIndex = searchColumnsList.findIndex(x=>x.name === fieldName);
        searchColumnsList[searchColumnIndex].searchText = searched;
        setSearchColumnsList(searchColumnsList);
        const searchColumns = searchColumnsList.filter(x=> x.searchText !== null && x.searchText !== '');
        const filterRows = searchColumns.length > 0 ? rows.filter(each => {
            let containRow = false;
            for (var i = 0; i < searchColumns.length; i++) {
                if (each[searchColumns[i].name] && each[searchColumns[i].name].toString().indexOf(searchColumns[i].searchText) !== -1) {
                containRow = true;
              }
              else{
                containRow = false;
              }
            }
            if (containRow) {
              return each;
            }
        }) : rows;
        setCopyList(filterRows);
    };
```

searchColumnsList this list variable will store the searches for every column.

jsx code for event requestSearch

```
<TableBody>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell>
                <TextField
                  variant='outlined'
                  placeholder='Search Name'
                  type='search'
                  onInput={e => requestSearch(e.target.value,'name')}
                  style={{ width: '100%' }}
                />
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell>
                <Typography variant='body2'>
                  <TextField
                    variant='outlined'
                    placeholder='Search Roll'
                    type='search'
                    onInput={e => requestSearch(e.target.value,'roll')}
                    style={{ width: '100%' }}
                  />{' '}
                </Typography>
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell>
                <Typography variant='body2'>
                  <TextField
                    variant='outlined'
                    placeholder='Search Result'
                    type='search'
                    onInput={e => requestSearch(e.target.value,'result')}
                    style={{ width: '100%' }}
                  />
                </Typography>
              </TableCell>            
            </TableRow>
          </TableBody>
```

Comment: "const [searchColumnsList, setSearchColumnsList] = useState(columnHeaders.map(x=> {return {name:x,searchText:null}}));"
Is falling saying  "FranchiseTable.jsx:162 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')"


Also I "searchColumnsList[searchColumnIndex].searchText = searched;"
Where is searchText Coming from

Comment: searchText is the key in which previous searched values will be saved its created object in the statement useState(columnHeaders.map(x=> {return {name:x,searchText:null}})); and columnHeaders is the variable with header column names in your code. before the return of jsx const columnHeaders = Object.values(headers);

Comment: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'searchText') when trying to find anything or type anything

Comment: would you please check the searchColumnsList variable or share the code for further investigation.

Comment: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {name: 'Name', searchText: null}
1: {name: 'Roll', searchText: null}
2: {name: 'Resu;ltRate', searchText: null}
Getting once I consoled  searchColumnsList 

and also  "Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'searchText') "*
@jahenzeb Naqvi

Comment: onInput={e => requestSearch(e.target.value,'result')} props passed to input elments. you will have to replace the second argument from 'result' to 'Resu;ltRate' and for all other input search field respectively 'Name','Roll' etc